# databinding a drop down list VS for each in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, webforms

what method of populating a drop down list is more efficient?

```
var info = db.table.Where( x => x.column == targetInformation).
           Select(x => new {x.item, x.index});

**************FOREACH
foreach( var infos in info)
{
   drowDownList.Items.Add(new {infos.item,infos.index.ToString()});
}
**************DATABIND
dropDownList.DataSource = info;
dropDownList.DataBind();
```

Comment: What makes you think there's a difference? Also, any difference will be overwhelmed by the fact that you're doing database I/O.

Comment: Define efficient first. If one line is efficienter than three, then the `DataBind` approach is more efficient. But in terms of  performance both are nearly equal because DataBind cannot work miracles.

Comment: your right, I should of defined efficient... I meant by readability and speed.  I think the second method look cleaner, just wanted other developer opinions.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by John Saunders, the efficiency here is not really something to consider especially considering the use of DB operations.

In other words, the performance of each is going to be very nearly the same.

What you should consider, though, is what is more efficient for you as a programmer to read? Also, are you going to be sharing this code with others on a team? Are they more used to WPF-style code, or the more manual style of code?

Perhaps the best efficiency to go for in this case is to maximize the readability of this code for you and your coworkers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little different, but you can try something like this:

```
var results = table.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<int>("SomeType") > 1);

foreach (DataRow row in results)
{
    dropDownList.Items.Add(row.Field<string>("SomeText"), row.Field<int>("SomeID"));
}

//you don't need to databind if you're adding the items manually
//dropDownList.DataSource = info; 
//dropDownList.DataBind();
```